# How to Create Documentation for Workflows using XML?

Tags: workflow, xml, automation, documentation

**Question:** How can I use an org's XML (retrieved from Eclipse or MavensMate) to "automate" my documentation? In other words, is there a way to "convert" or manipulate the XML for each workflow into a decent, complete documentation document? Would there also by a way to retrieve the URL's for each component involved (i.e. workflow rule, workflow action, etc.)

**Background:** I am a Consultant dealing with 20+ Salesforce instances and need to do a better job documenting system automations in case something ever happens to me... and, quite frankly, documentation is just the right thing to do for my clients. After much "manual labor" I have documented over 130 workflow rules for a handful of clients, capturing the following:

1. Workflow unique "business case" (organizational requirement for automation)
2. "Components" (fields involved with workflow automation, workflow actions, email templates, etc.)
3. Narrative Summary (layman's description of  how the workflow is achieving it's purpose).

That being said, I still have 100's of more workflows to document and am hoping there is a more efficient way. I think this background info is important to understand my question.

Comment: Perhaps there is a 3rd party tool that does this... Otherwise it's a fair bit of work in your favourite programming language perhaps using XSLT.

Comment: MyDossier is the only app on the app exchange and it doesn't support workflows. I have not come across any other 3rd party tool.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about documenting requirements from the technical implementation. The three items you mentioned should be documented before creating the WFs and the implementation saved in your version control system.

Comment: @MikeChale I agree, but working in the nonprofit sector, most clients don't have these things in place and now I'm trying to get them there: hence, my specific question about manipulating the XML code. Your input is absolutely valid, just doesn't address my actual question at hand.

Comment: If you are comfortable writing code yourself to do this, I suggest using npm's xml2js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to convert your xml data into a javascript object. You can then easily work with the object data in an npm script to pull out the data you need and save it as JSON or in some other format. While this does not get you all the way to your documentation, having a process that creates JSON file with the relevant data for your documentation is a big step. You could then consume that JSON to create whatever documentation you want. Note: This is a lot of work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sublime Text, try the plugin [haoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide)

It is more robust than Octupus since it allows you to download .csv files for Workflows. 
 I also set up a simple mail merge using Word and Excel to make a presentable deliverable to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Octopus app which seems to at least help with automating some of the documentation process...https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ